# Laravel Mix doesn't output css files

Tags: php, npm, webpack, laravel-5.4, laravel-mix

I've cloned the code at master branch on [rappasof/laravel-5-boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate) and was able to run `npm install` followed by `npm run dev`. It does process the scss files, as it generates the font files, but the css files are not been generated.

I'm running on:

- Windows 10 x64
- node.js 8.1.0
- npm 5.0.3

This is the output from `npm run dev`:

```
PS D:\DevProjects\laravel-5-boilerplate.lar> npm run dev

> @ dev D:\DevProjects\laravel-5-boilerplate.lar
> npm run development


> @ development D:\DevProjects\laravel-5-boilerplate.lar
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

 95% emitting

 DONE  Compiled successfully in 3399ms                                                                                                                              02:02:31


                                                                                                    Asset       Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
                       fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?b06871f281fee6b241d60582ae9369b9     166 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1    20.1 kB          [emitted]
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf?e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512    45.4 kB          [emitted]
 fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff?fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158    23.4 kB          [emitted]
fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb      18 kB          [emitted]
                       fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.eot?674f50d287a8c48dc19ba404d20fe713     166 kB          [emitted]
                       fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.svg?912ec66d7572ff821749319396470bde     444 kB          [emitted]  [big]
  fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg?89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760     109 kB          [emitted]
                     fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e    77.2 kB          [emitted]
                      fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?fee66e712a8a08eef5805a46892932ad      98 kB          [emitted]
                                                                                          /js/frontend.js    1.21 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  /js/frontend
                                                                                           /js/backend.js     980 kB       1  [emitted]  [big]  /js/backend
                                                                                                   mix.js     619 kB       2  [emitted]  [big]  mix
                                                                                        mix-manifest.json  256 bytes          [emitted]
```

No css files emitted!

I'm using laravel on top of apache, so I'm getting an error on the assets urls because they are absolute from root, as `http://localhost:8000/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e` and what I need is `http://localhost:8000/my-project/fonts/vendor/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?af7ae505a9eed503f8b8e6982036873e`.

After some digging, I've found that if I add `mix.setResourceRoot('/my-project/');` in the `webpack.mix.js` file, I could generate the links to assets correctly, but I can't get Laravel Mix to output the corrected css files.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Post your `webpack.mix.js` file